# Gem install doesn't create link to bin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm trying to install `cocoapods` on Mac

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.25.0
1 gem installed
```

But

```
$ pod install
-bash: pod: command not found
```

Ruby was installed using `brew`

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

$ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
```

Here is output of `gem environment`

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/nt/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

What I should export or add to .bash_profile to get `pod install` working?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) like I am, after installing a gem you have to run **rbenv rehash** to get a link in the shims directory.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, this line in `.bash_profile` helped

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin
```